# office.js: Outlook Web displays "Save/Discard/Cancel" dialog on appointment close

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office-app

I have an Outlook Add-In written in the new Javascript API (office.js).

I do some manipulations from the compose form on an appointment in the calendar (adding subject suffix and some text to body). After I finish the manipulations I call:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(callback)
```

the item with my changes get saved, however when I call `Office.context.mailbox.item.close()` **or** just close the appointment compose form on the outlook web UI - a dialog is displayed if I want to save my changes or discard them, altough there were no changed made since the `saveAsync` call.

Regardless if the user clicks Save or Discard, the appointment has the changes I made with the add-in before the `saveAsync` call. What can be the reason for such behavior?

Comment: I encounter the same behaviour... any updates on that?

Comment: Unfortunately not